# Find a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP files - one with a couple of serials and another one that checks those serials.
I only know a part of the serial, e.g. "123" - how to get the rest of it? (the part: **-unused_**)

1:

```
$serial = "123";

$path_to_file = 'serials.php';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

if(strrchr($file_contents,$serial) != false){
$file_contents = str_replace($serial, $serial."_used_+1",$file_contents);    
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
```

2:

```
$serials = array("123-unused_", "456-used+3_", "789-used+1_");
```

Comment: more details? Is the first part always 3 characters? Are you going to need to match on one, or multiple partial serials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the second part of the serial always starts with "-", you could use this code:

```
for($i=0;;$i++){
if($serials[$i]==""){break;}
$expl = explode("-",$serials[$i]);
if($expl[0] == $serial){
echo '-'.$expl[1]; //print the second part of the serial
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I would recommend the following:

```
class ArrayUtil
{
    public function IsStrInArray($str, $array)
    {
        foreach($array as $item)
        {
            if (strpos($item, $str) !== false)
                return $item;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$arr = array("123-unused_", "456-used+3_", "789-used+1_");

var_dump(ArrayUtil::IsStrInArray('-unused', $arr));
```

Output:

> string(11) "123-unused_"

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of big function names for what you want to do. Let's assume you have 1 or more partial serials, your real keys are always (three, dash, more), and you need to match lots of serials.

```
// note the pass-by-reference: we don't need a copy of $serials. Just access.
function findSerialsIn(&$serials, $filepath) {
  $found = array();
  $file = file($path_to_file);
  foreach($file as $line) {
    $partial = explode('-',$line)[0];
    if(in_array($partial, $serials)) {
      $found[] = trim($line);
    }
  }
  return $found;
}

$serials = array("123", "456", ...);
$filepath = "....";
$found = findSerialsIn($serials, $filepath);

print "found: " . implode(", ", $found);
```